# Evaluate every value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´m having trouble making a query. I hope someone could help me.

Let´s say I have a database something like this.

```
DateandTime  PartNum  FwVerOrErrDesc  Pass
date1          A             1         0
date2          A             1         0
date3          B             1         0
date4          B             3         0
date5          C             2         0
date6          A             3         0
date7          C             1         0
date8          B             2         0
date9          B             1         0
```

Summarying I have dates, a type of model in this example A, B and C but in the actual database I have over 100 different models, on the FwVerOrErrDesc I have a type of failure and again I have many types of failure, and the Pass indicates the unit failed.

I want to generate a query that tells me how many units have failed in an specific failure, but, since there are failures that are the same on different models I just can´t count the failures (FwVerOrErrDesc) and order by them cause I just get the total of failures lets say "1" but of all models and I want to be discriminated by models as well. (PartNum is model)

What I´m trying to achive is something like this.

```
PartNum  FwVerOrErrDesc  Count
   A           1           2
   A           3           1
   B           1           2
   B           2           1
   B           3           1
   C           1           1
   C           2           1
```

I tried with something like this:

```
SELECT
    PartNum
,   [FwVerOrErrDesc]
, COUNT(FwVerOrErrDesc)

FROM [RceTestwareMfrLog].[dbo].[RceLogData]
  WHERE Pass=0 and DateAndTime > DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T06:00:00')
  and DateAndTime < DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T14:00:00') and
  substring(SerialNum,1,8) <> '11111111'
  GROUP BY [PartNum]
```

But I got an error.

I hope someone could help me, and thank you very much in advantage.

Comment: You are missing `FwVerOrErrDesc` from the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include [FwVerOrErrDesc] column in Group by clause. Try this

```
SELECT
    PartNum
,   [FwVerOrErrDesc]
, COUNT(FwVerOrErrDesc) as [count]

FROM [RceTestwareMfrLog].[dbo].[RceLogData]
  WHERE Pass=0 and DateAndTime > 
  DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T06:00:00')
  and DateAndTime < DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',GETDATE()),'2001-01-01T14:00:00') 
  and
  substring(SerialNum,1,8) <> '11111111'
  GROUP BY [PartNum],[FwVerOrErrDesc]
```

Comment: I feel such silly right now, lol, it was so simple but I couldn´t figure it out. Thank you. You have helped me great deal. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I would write the query as:

```
SELECT PartNum, FwVerOrErrDesc, COUNT(FwVerOrErrDesc)
FROM [RceTestwareMfrLog].[dbo].[RceLogData]
WHERE Pass = 0 AND
      DATEPART(hour, DateAndTime) BETWEEN 6 AND 13 AND
      SerialNum NOT LIKE '11111111%'
GROUP BY PartNum, FwVerOrErrDesc;
```

Of course, the issue (as I mentioned in the comment) is the missing column in the `GROUP BY`.  In addition:

- This uses `NOT LIKE` rather than `SUBSTRING()`.  `LIKE` can make use of an index when the pattern starts with non-wildcards, so it is good habit to use the patterns.
- This extracts the hour explicitly for the time comparison.  You could also do something like `cast(DateAndTime as time) between '06:00:00' and '14:00:00'`.

Comment: Thank you, I´ll take into account your advices.  Have a nice day.